# Pass a service to a generic controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using a modular approach for my angular project.
I have two modules 'A' and 'B'. Both have a list page that should use the same controller stored in /shared/ListCtrl.

The only difference between A and B is the backend service they use to get the list.
Even the services are quite identical except of the API uri so they behave equally.

Now I want to add ListCtrl to module A:

```
var listServiceA = SomeService;
.controller('ListCtrlA', ListCtrl); // And now I want to pass listServiceA in
```

Module B will do the same but will use listServiceB.
So regular DI won't work as ListCtrl doesn't need to know if it deals with ServiceA or ServiceB. How can this be achieved?

**Update:**
In a static typed language: Create a static controller that takes any object of type Service and perform operations on it.
Or create a class that takes an object of type service in the constructor.

I think a controller is more like case 1 and I need a way to pass the service to it when adding it to a module.

Comment: why don not u design service to take input from outside

Comment: Doesn't this simply shift the problem into another component?
Then the controller needs to configure the service and I have still to tell the controller which service it has to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`$providers`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). I thinks it's pretty much exactly what your're looking for. Demo could be:

```
<div id="module-a" data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  Module A: {{url}}
</div>

<div id="module-b" data-ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  Module B: {{url}}
</div>

<script>
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('module-a'), ['A']);
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('module-b'), ['B']);
</script>
```

with:

```
/**
 * shared code
 */
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * the shared controller
   */
  app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'ListService', function ($scope, ListService) {
    $scope.url = ListService.getUrl();
  }]);

  /**
   * the shared service
   */
  function ListService(url) {
    function getUrl() {
      return url;
    }

    // public api
    return {
      getUrl: getUrl
    };
  }

  /**
   * the list service provider
   */
  app.provider('ListService', function ListServiceProvider() {
    var url = null;

    this.setUrl = function(newUrl) {
      url = newUrl;
    };

    this.$get = [function ListServiceFactory() {
      return new ListService(url);
    }];
  });
}(angular.module('shared', []), angular));


/**
 * Module: A
 */
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.config(['ListServiceProvider', function (ListServiceProvider) {
    ListServiceProvider.setUrl('#/ModuleA');
  }]);

}(angular.module('A', ['shared']), angular));


/**
 * Module: B
 */
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.config(['ListServiceProvider', function (ListServiceProvider) {
    ListServiceProvider.setUrl('#/ModuleB');
  }]);

}(angular.module('B', ['shared']), angular));
```

live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/hfDoJup0nS0URKsEo2Cu

Comment: This looks more complicated than I thought but I think it accomplishes what I want. I'll give it a try later!

Comment: @DanielKhan I think that's just because there is so much boilerplate code for this example. But in the end it's just the provider-code and the config call. So only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Class.js](https://github.com/rauschma/class-js) to create a generic controller and two specifics controllers that inherits of the generic controller.